# can you set c++ flags using the BASH make and cmake commands?

Tags: debian, g++

I'm using MX Linux debian 10 (buster), so I don't think I can update the compiler. Is there a way I can depreciate, or modify so that it is backwards compatible? For example, I am trying to compile Btop, but when I run `make` I'm getting the error g++:

```
error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++20’; did you mean ‘-std=c++2a’?
```

Can I add some flags or something when I run `make` so that it runs as an older version of g++ for compilation? I searched all the code and I couldn't even find a line where it said 'c++20'. Mind you, I am not a programmer, so I might have missed it.

N.B. when I ran `g++ -v`, it said I was running version 8.3.0, that seems a lot older than 20, unless I'm misunderstanding it.

Similarly, I was trying to compile tenacity (the audacity fork) and when I run `cmake .` I get:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.15 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.13.4
```

Is there also a solution for this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: btop is OK with g++ 10.3 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing → `gcc10-c++_10.3.0-1pio-10_amd64.deb` .......... Edit btop/Makefile, line 38 to `g++ = g++-10` . ......... About 'cmake' : `cmake_3.16.3` is in "buster-backports" https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/cmake

Comment: Thanks for the reply Knud, so I'm assuming this will take me from g++ 8.3 to 10.3. What is the origin of the `gcc10-c++_10.3.0-1pio-10_amd64.deb` you provided? Just out of interest. Also thanks for the cmake backport, I am still fairly new, and I was wondering, what determines whether something gets a backport made or not? Or is it just the luck of the draw? Cheers!

Comment: Like the other "gccXX-c++" in the link, it's created by me. All the other versions were built on request. The gcc10-c++_10.3.0 was built to be used for my own experiments. ( I have built gcc compilers for many years, usually built to have no dependencies, except libc.)

Comment: Hi Knud, a couple of questions, so there are a dozen files in there, aside from `gcc10-c++_10.3.0-1pio-10_amd64.deb`, do I need to install all of them? Because I installed the aforementioned and `gcc -v` still says it's version 8.3....perhaps I also need to reboot? Also, the cmake backport won't install, it says `Error: dependency is not satisfiable: cmake-data (=3.16.3-3~bpo10+1)`, is there a way to debug and perhaps fix this? Thanks very much!

Comment: gcc -v is the default gcc. Please do `gcc-10 -v` ....... and for 'btop' please remember to edit Makefile line 38 to `CXX = g++-10` .

Comment: Hi Knud, you were correct about `gcc-10 -v`. I changed Line 38 like you said, and I changed line 82 from c++20 to `override REQFLAGS   := -std=c++17` however now I'm getting the error, excerpt: `Compiling src/btop_config.cpp
src/btop_config.cpp:20:10: fatal error: ranges: No such file or directory
 #include <ranges>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:187: obj/btop_config.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
src/btop.cpp:25:10: fatal error: ranges: No such file or directory
 #include <ranges>'
Does this mean anything to you? Thanks again!!

Comment: P.S. when you said gcc is the default gcc, how do I know it actually used gcc-10 when I ran `make`? Is there a way to set gcc-10 as the default gcc? And on the topic of tenacity, did this mean that the cmake backport just won't work and that I'll need to compile it? Thank you once again

Comment: No reason to set an extra gcc as default. Any of the many extra gcc's can be used as, e.g. `export CC=gcc-10 CXX=g++-10 && [other-command]` or `make CXX=g++-10` . ....... With the actual Makefile the solution is : Edit line 38 to `CXX = g++-10` .... and don't edit anything else.

Comment: cmake : Example enabling backports https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports ..... Ref. Google, ubuntu enable backports

Comment: Hi again Knud, we're getting close! `CXX=g++-10` allowed it to compile! However, when I tried to run it, I got the message `btop: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by btop)`...I don't suppose you have any idea what I need to update to fix this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Either start btop with pointing to (a copy of) `/usr/local/gcc10.3.0/lib64/{libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28` ..... or copy  libstdc++.so.6.0.28 to /usr/lib/, and create the link libstdc++.so.6 .

Comment: Hi Knud, I'm sorry can you please be a bit more explicit? When you say point point btop, is that like `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gcc10.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28`? I didn't understand that. Also, when you said to "link libstdc++.so.6", is that like `ln -s /usr/local/gcc10.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/bin`? I'm still learning, thanks again!

Comment: PATH is for executable. ....... Libs : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc10.3.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [start-command]` ......... ←(You can make start script with that text) ........... (Alternatively copy libstdc++.so.6.0.28 to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` , and create the link libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28 ).

Comment: Hi Knad, Good to hear from you. I tried both of those things and both worked! I deleted the libstdc++ link in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and replaced it with the .so.6.0.28 file. However, regarding the script or command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc10.3.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can you just explain what this is actually doing to the loader? Particularly the end part `:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` why is that in there again? Thank you very much

Comment: Not about a "loader", but required when you start / are using an app or library depending on libstdc++.so.6 from a later gcc / g++ version.

Comment: Hi Knud, I see, fair enough. From what I can see the `...:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is just part of the code, like syntax, and has to be used in the `export` command, not specific to what we did. So I think everything makes sense now. I appreciate the great help you've been. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using MX Linux debian 10 (buster), so I don't think I can update the compiler.

Of course you can. You can compile gcc from source (for whatever version) and install it locally. Though the latter is a bit of an effort.

You could also switch to a new Debian version, and save yourself this effort.

> [Btop] Can I add some flags or something when I run make so that it runs as an older version of g++ for compilation?

Look at the Makefile for Btop, figure out what sets the flags (`make -p` helps), either change the Makefile directly, or change whatever files Btop uses to produce the Makefile.

> it said I was running version 8.3.0, that seems a lot older than 20

It's about the C++ standard version, not about the gcc version. Have a look at [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) to see which gcc version supports which language standard version.

Not that if the Btop source code really uses features from a standard that's not supported by the compiler, then the source code for Btop obviously won't compile. If they just put it in there because they wanted to define the standard version to use, it still might compile under an older standard.

> CMake 3.15 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.13.4

Same problem as above: Compile Cmake from source, or upgrade your Debian version so you can use newer packages.

Comment: Hi dirkt, thanks for the reply. I'm not at home currently, but I will look into the Btop makefile. Thanks for the information regarding the c++ standard versions, for experience I would like to compile g++ from source, but I am also wondering, what are the implications of switching to a newer Debian version? Won't this break a lot of the compatibility/dependencies of all the programmes I have already installed? I appreciate that it does sound like the easier solution, if it doesn't break anything in doing so. Cheers!

Comment: The implications of switching to a newer Debian version is that you need to upgrade a lot of the packages. Once you've done this, everything works fine again. There's an `apt-get` command to switch.

Comment: Thanks dirkt, definitely worth considering. I'm going to pursue compilation first though lol. Cheers!